# How to vertical center <li> element in <ul>?

Tags: html, css

I was experimenting with html and css by creating a navbar. I find it hard to position an element using html. While on Android it's quite easy to do that (well, it took me some time to know how).

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 64px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

div#brand {
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 2em;
    float: left;
}
div p {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#menu {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block; /* to make list horizontal */
    margin: 0 1.25em;
}

nav li:hover {
    background: gray;
}

nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mijn navbar</title>

    <!-- include index.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="brand"><p>My Brand</p></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>    
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the content or text of the li elements vertically centred with the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added some CSS in the end,
using flex-box to center

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 64px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

div#brand {
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 2em;
    float: left;
}
div p {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#menu {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block; /* to make list horizontal */
    margin: 0 1.25em;
}

nav li:hover {
    background: gray;
}

nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

/* below lines were added */
#menu,
#menu ul {
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 #menu ul li{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mijn navbar</title>

    <!-- include index.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="brand"><p>My Brand</p></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is flex-box vanilla css? I mean it's part of CSS3 and not some additional trick?

Comment: support is quite good nowadays and i think everyone is using it, so not a trick IMO

Comment: see this please https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 64px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

div#brand {
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 2em;
    float: left;
}
div p {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#menu {
    float: right;
        padding: 22px;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block; /* to make list horizontal */
    margin: 0 1.25em;
}

nav li:hover {
    background: gray;
}

nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mijn navbar</title>

    <!-- include index.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="brand"><p>My Brand</p></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>    
</body>
</html>
```

added just :

```
    padding: 22px;
```

Comment: Problem is, if I make the navbar like 100 px high, I have to adjust the padding again.